# building docker image of software with dependency files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and would like to know how I can build a docker image with dependencies. I have tried the standard way of putting the docker file into the directory of the exe. This directory also contains all the dependant files. The image builds but I get a syntax error when I try run it.
This is the error:

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

The docker file I am using has the following code:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY . /myapplication
CMD node myapplication/APP.exe
```

running on windows commandline:

```
docker build -t myapplication .
```

builds without errors and

```
docker run myapplication
```

throws the error above

Comment: Where does `APP.exe` come from?  Is it actually a Javascript source file, or some sort of compiled (Windows) executable?

Comment: Its a compiled windows application. its a very big application with a lot of config files

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to run it via `node` as you've shown, nor will you be able to run it at all in a Linux container.

Comment: What kind of alternative wrap up could I do?